# An Expression for $\log\zeta(ns)$ derived from the Limit of the truncated Prime $\zeta$ Function

Tags: special-functions, approximation, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I think, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115230/19341), I found 
$$
P_\color{red}x(\color{blue}s)=\sum_{p<\color{red}x} \frac{1}{p^{\color{blue}s}} =\sum_{\color{green}n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \mu (\color{green}n)}{\color{green}n}
\sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\}}(-1)^{1-\delta_{1z}}
\left[
{\rm li}(t^{\frac z{\color{green}n}-\color{blue}s})
\right]^{\color{red}x}_2
\tag{7},
$$
where $\rho$ are **all** the zeros (trivial and non-trivial) of $\zeta$ function.  See the linked question for more detail, corrections are welcome.
Further we know, that
$$
    P(\color{blue}{s})=\sum_{\color{green}n>0}\frac {\mu(\color{green}n)}{\color{green}n}{\log\zeta(\color{green}n\color{blue}s)} 
$$
(if you forgot, see [here/WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function) or [here/MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html)).

So my question is

> If
>   $\lim_{\color{red}x\to \infty} P_{\color{red}x}(\color{blue}s)=P(\color{blue}s) $
>   then, by comparing coefficients, is
>   $$
> \log\zeta(\color{green}n\color{blue}s)=\lim_{\color{red}x\to \infty}
> \sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\}}(-1)^{1-\delta_{1z}}
> \left[
> {\rm li}(t^{\frac1n(z-\color{green}n\color{blue}s)})
> \right]^{\color{red}x}_2
> ?
> $$

What I got so far is:

- [Thanks to robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/285413/19341) it possible to see that both coincide at least some special values:
  If $\color{green}n\color{blue}s=1$ or $\color{green}n\color{blue}s=\rho_k$, one addend in the sum diverges like $\lim_{\color{red}x\to\infty} \log\left(\frac{\log(\color{red}x)}{\log(2)}\right)=\infty$. So we get 
  $$
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \color{green}n\color{blue}s=1: & \log(\zeta(1)) &=& +\infty &=& 
  \phantom{-}\left[
  {\rm li}(t^{0})
  \right]^{\color{red}x}_2 +\sum_{z\in\{\rho\}}
  \cdots \\
  \color{green}n\color{blue}s=\rho_k: & \log(\zeta(\rho)) &=& -\infty &=&
  -\left[
  {\rm li}(t^{0})
  \right]^{\color{red}x}_2 +\sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\} / \rho_k}
  \cdots \\
  \end{eqnarray}
  $$
- I looked at the series expansion at $\color{blue}s=0$ for ${\rm li}(\color{red}x^{\frac1{\color{green}n}(z-\color{green}i\color{green}n\color{blue}s)})=$ 
  [${\rm Ei}\biggr((\frac z{\color{green}n}-i\color{blue}s)\ln(\color{red}x)\biggr)$](http://tinyurl.com/b57ga7j) and [$\log\zeta(i\color{green}n\color{blue}s)$](http://tinyurl.com/a3tvnml) (Forget about the $i$, if you like. It was just a try). Assuming I'm not wrong, you'll get the following when you compare the linear terms
  $$
  \log(2\pi) \overset{?}{=} 
  \lim_{\color{red}x\to \infty}\sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\}}(-1)^{\delta_{1z}}
  \left[ \frac{ t^{\frac{z}{\color{green}n}}}{z}\right]_2^{\color{red}x} ,
  $$
  which looks a little irritating, since the RHS has to be independent of $\color{red}x$ and $\color{green}n$. Does this show that it's wrong at all?
- Could $  \displaystyle  \log \zeta(\color{blue}s) = \color{blue}s \int_0^\infty \frac{\pi(x)}{x(x^{\color{blue}s}-1)}\,dx $ be useful somehow?

Comment: Cross-posted at [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119210/11856)...

Comment: Im pretty sure an inverse laplace transform is used with that integral to get an explict formula for the reimann prime counting function, though I don't know much about complex analysis.